# Conditional navigation bar

Tags: view, ruby-on-rails-3.1, conditional-statements

Hello Guys I've a request for you.I've Drinks, Menus and Users routes.
I've this code in `views/layout/application.html.erb`:

```
<div>
<%= render "shared/navigation_bar"
</div>
```

How to make the `navigation_bar` to render in all the pages except in users pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally work around many methods, but I finally come up with a solution(not really stunnin',  I must confess) , that works for me.

```
<div>
<% if controller.controller_name == "drinks" %>
  <%= render "shared/navigation_bar" %>
<% elsif controller.controller_name == "menus" %>
  <%= render "shared/navigation_bar" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

The flow control doesn't include Users's controller, so the navigation_bar layout won't appear on User's pages.

That's it.If you guys have a better alternative just let me know.